# The probability that a tossed coin lands heads is p. What are the possible values of p, and which of these values is plausible for a physical coin?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, elementary-probability

> The probability that a tossed coin lands heads is $p$. When the coin is tossed twice, it is equally
>   likely that both tosses are the same and that the tosses are not both tails. What are the possible values of $p$,
>   and which of these values is plausible for a physical coin?

From what I understand, getting $Pr(Head)=p$, so then $Pr(Tail)=1-p$.

This part I cannot understand:

> When the coin is tossed twice, it is equally
>   likely that both tosses are the same and that the tosses are not both tails.

Does this mean that both tosses are tails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stated equality means
$$P(HH+HT+TH)=P(HH+TT)$$
$$P(HT+TH)=P(TT)$$
$$2p(1-p)=(1-p)^2$$
Either $p=1$ or
$$2p=1-p\implies p=\frac13$$
So $p=1\lor p=\frac13$, but only $p=\frac13$ is plausible for a physical coin.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot for clarifying the question.